# VBA, For Each Application Match, object required

Tags: excel, vba

Having an issue looping through application match.
I get an error `Object required` on line `K.Offset(0, 1).Copy FV.Offset(2, 0)`

The code should

1) loop through CS range,

2) where CS matches in range FV,

3) input the cells from CS Offset(0,1) into FV 2 columns over, Offset(2,0).

Here is my full code:

```
Sub n()

Dim FV As Variant
Dim CS As Variant
Dim K As Variant

FV = Sheets("NEW").Range("A28:A34").Value
CS = Sheets("CS").Range("A1:L1").Value

For Each K In CS
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(CS, FV, 0)) Then
        K.Offset(0, 1).Copy FV.Offset(2, 0)
        Else:
    End If
Next K

End Sub
```

Comment: CS etc. are not ranges, they are arrays. Please have a look [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array) how to work with array

Comment: Neither `K` nor `FV` are range objects.  One is a single value, the other is a 2D array of values. Therefore they will not have an `Offset` property.

Comment: Sorry guys, my mistake, i tried to make it look abit cleaner, the `variant` variables are actually spelled right now.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld would `Cells` work instead of `Offset`?

Comment: you want a For Loop for array. You are trying to match using an array with CS when you should be using a single value. And k is not a range object as stated. By using .Value you are generating 2D arrays.

Comment: `Cells` is not a property of the array, either, so no.  You need to set `Range` objects in order to have a base from which to copy/paste values.

Comment: Drop .Value from CS and add set keyword and declare as range. Turn FV into a single D array with transpose. And search for k.value maybe? I think there is overall a logic problem that needs sorting.

Comment: It might be helpful for you to read the HELP pages for information as to  [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and, **especially** [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Hard to tell from your question exactly what you have for data, and what you want for results.

Comment: Could you please confirm that you are using cellFV.Offset(0, 2).Value = cellCS.Offset(1, 0).Value instead of cellFV.Offset(2, 0).Value = cellCS.Offset(0, 1).Value, or post the code you are using, I would like to give arrays a go.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I'm using `cellFV.Offset(0, 3).Value = CellCS.Offset(1, 0).Value` . So output to FV into the 3rd column, and copy from CS 1 row down. I'll test your answer shortly.

Comment: Then just change '2' to '3' in the offset in the last line of my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a pure VBA function like:

```
Sub CopyMatchingValues()
    Dim FV As Range
    Dim CS As Range
    Dim cellFV As Range
    Dim cellCS As Range

    Set FV = Sheets("NEW").Range("A28:A34")
    Set CS = Sheets("CS").Range("A1:L1")

    For Each cellCS In CS.Cells
        For Each cellFV In FV.Cells
            If cellFV.Value = cellCS.Value Then
                cellFV.Offset(2, 0).Value = cellCS.Offset(0, 1).Value
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, just had to adjust the offset, i got rows and cols mixed.

Comment: yeah was much more easier to understand, just wish.. i knew.. about.. looping with arrays.

Answer (score 2):

## What a Match feat. the FirstMatch Issue

```
Option Explicit

Sub XMatch()

  Const FirstMatch As Boolean = True
  Dim FV As Variant     ' Search Array (Vertical)
  Dim CS As Variant     ' Source Array (Horizontal)
  Dim K As Variant      ' Target Array (Vertical)
  Dim iFV As Integer    ' Search Array Rows Counter
  Dim iCS As Integer    ' Source Array Columns Counter

  ' Paste ranges into arrays.
  FV = Sheets("NEW").Range("A28:A34").Value       ' Search Array = Search Range
  CS = Sheets("CS").Range("A1:L2").Value          ' Source Array = Source Range

  ' The Target Array is the same size as the Search Array.
  ReDim K(1 To UBound(FV), 1 To 1)
  ' ReDim K(LBound(FV, 1) To UBound(FV, 1), LBound(FV, 2) To UBound(FV, 2))

  ' Loop through first and only COLUMN of first dimension of Search Array.
  For iFV = 1 To UBound(FV)
  ' For iFV = LBound(FV, 1) To UBound(FV, 1)

    ' Loop through first ROW of second dimension of Source Array.
    For iCS = 1 To UBound(CS, 2)
    ' For iCS = LBound(CS, 2) To UBound(CS, 2)

      If FV(iFV, 1) = CS(1, iCS) Then
        ' Match is found, read from second ROW of the second dimension of Source
        ' Array and write to first and only COLUMN of first dimension of Target
        ' Array.
        K(iFV, 1) = CS(2, iCS)
        ' Check True/False
        If FirstMatch Then
          ' When FirstMatch True, stop searching.
          Exit For
'         Else
          ' When FirstMatch False, try to find another match to use as result.
        End If
'       Else
        ' Match is not found.
      End If

    Next

  Next

  ' Paste Target Array into Target Range, which is two columns to the right of
  ' Search Range.
  Sheets("NEW").Range("A28:A34").Offset(0, 2) = K ' Target Range = Target Array

End Sub
```

Comment: Very Nice! thanks! Works 10X faster then the above one too. How could I add more of these/more "sources" ? Ie say I want to copy and paste from another sheet into FV following a similar match logic?

Comment: Post another question and we'll see. After a few of those you'll be able to make your own. You can find some more examples in my answers where there are better explanations. Feel free to ask anything that's not clear to you.

Comment: I do got a question. If I want to loop through another array (Vertical this time).  How can I loop through a column, instead of a row, ie you have    `For iCS = 1 To UBound(CS, 2)` to loop through a row, but now i want to loop through a vertical array.

Comment: In 'For iCS = 1 To UBound(CS, 2)', the 2 indicates by column, so the answer is 'For iCS = 1 To UBound(CS, 1)' or shorter 'For iCS = 1 To UBound(CS)'. I don't think that the terms vertical and horizontal are in use, I'm just using them to indicate where more rows or more columns are to better visualize i.e. the 2 represents the second dimension (or columns), and the 1 the first (or rows) (which can be omitted). A good analogy to ranges would be UBound(CS, 1) = Rows.Count and UBound(CS, 2) = Columns.Count. Maybe you could replace iFV with 'i' and iCS with 'j' to make it more readable for you.

Comment: You can also see this in the line 'For iFV = 1 To UBound(FV)'. Better practice is to always declare the rows like in this case iFV as Long which I completely missed. Usually, when I declare variables, I like to include their type so using 'my way' CS would be vntCS with row counter lngCS and column counter intCS and similarly, FV would be vntFV with lngFV (for rows) and intFV (for columns) which might help in readability. Now when you read through the code and you see 'vnt...' - 'aHa, array', 'int...' - 'aHa, columns' and 'lng...' - 'aHa, rows'. You might be better off with row... and col...

Comment: Thanks. one more question, If I try to do a column array as a source array, how can I choose a column in this array? In the answer we use the row below in the source array. How to return columns across in the source array?

Comment: In the line 'If FV(iFV, 1) = CS(1, iCS) Then' the 1 is indicating which column or which row. You can put any number instead if there are more columns or rows. In our case FV has only one column but if there where more you could choose any instead of 1.

Comment: if CS was A:C, how could i alter that line to return a column and not a row? FV will be always constant.